# How to list all user workspaces using slack api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

After we get the user access token using `Sign in with slack`, we can query identity information as shown below:

```
{
  ok: true,
  user: {
    name: 'arbxxxxxxx',
    id: 'U0XXXXXXX',
    email: 'arbxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com'
  },
  team: { id: 'T0XXXXXXX' },
  response_metadata: {
    scopes: [ 'identity.basic', 'identity.email', 'openid' ],
    acceptedScopes: [ 'identity.basic' ]
  }
}
```

The current workspace is `team: { id: 'T0XXXXXXX' }`.

How can I get all the other workspaces?

FYI: Sign in and acces token usage is shown in at this gist: https://gist.github.com/seratch/92bf98679d7a37a87dfa7376d02a51a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of [Org Apps](https://api.slack.com/enterprise/apps) installed on a Grid, users actually auth *per* workspace, and each is a unique identity, there's no real concept of a single identity that spans across workspaces

Comment: I mark it as correct answer, considering it as not possible in our case. Thanks Colm!